# (intel syntax) What constraints do I need to put below these assembly codes

Tags: gcc, x86, intel, inline-assembly, spinlock

```
/*
*       - spin lock aessembly code.
*
*   Implement spin lock in assembly level. 
*/


         #include <sys/types.h>
         #include <pthread.h>

         #include "lab2_sync_types.h"

         #define LOCK_PREFIX "lock\n\t"

         void atomic_add( int * value, int add_val) {

         asm volatile(
                LOCK_PREFIX
            "addl %1, %0      \n\t"
            : "+m"(*value)
            : "ir"(add_val)
            : /*no clobber-list*/
            ); }

        void atomic_sub( int * value, int dec_val) {

        asm volatile(
            LOCK_PREFIX
            "subl %1, %0      \n\t"
            : "+m"(*value)
            : "ir"(dec_val)
            : /*no clobber-list*/
            );

}

void atomic_inc( int * value) {

    asm volatile(
            LOCK_PREFIX
            "incl %0        \n\t"
            : "+m"(*value)
            : /* no input */
            : /*no clobber-list*/
            );

}

void atomic_dec( int * value) {

    asm volatile(
            LOCK_PREFIX
            "decl %0        \n\t"
            : "+m"(*value)
            : /* no input */
            : /*no clobber-list*/
            );

}

void lab2_spin_lock(int volatile *lock) {

    asm volatile(
            "mov eax, 1     \n\t"
            "loop:  \n\t"
            "xchg eax, %0   \n\t"
            "test eax, eax  \n\t"
            "jnz loop       \n\t"
            :"=r"(*lock)
            :
            :"eax","cc"
            );    

}

void lab2_spin_unlock(int volatile *lock) {

     asm volatile(
            "mov eax, 0   \n\t"
            "xchg eax, %0   \n\t"
            :"=r"(*lock)
            :
            :"eax"
            );

}
```

hello, and thank you for reading this question.

I was wondering what kind of constrains(which comes after :) do I need to put below those codes to make this inline assembly function properly.

Just in case you might not follow, these are implement of spinlock in assembly.

It would be grateful if you can give me a solution thanks.

Comment: Inline assembly is hard to get right and error prone. Have you considered just creating an assembly language file (you can assemble with something like _NASM_). You can assemble it to an object and just link it with your project.

Comment: thank you for a comment but I really need to stick to this syntax since it's my assigment

Comment: NASM is intel syntax.

Comment: Even the syntax you have shown won't work (`move` isn't an instruction), LOCK_PREFIX must be defined somewhere else but you don't show it, and `volatole` is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: oh, sorry my bad.

Comment: Kept you waiting, this is the entire code

Comment: You can't use a lock prefix on a `mov` instruction, it will cause the processor to raise an exception.

Comment: "memory" needs to be added to the clobber list in order to prevent memory references that are protected by these operation being moved past them.

Comment: Just to clarify Timothy's comment, adding the "memory" clobber prevents the *compiler* from moving memory references either before or after the add/sub instruction.  The "lock" prefix already prevents the CPU's OoO from doing the same.